# Trouble importing dll library into CodeBlocks Linker

Tags: c++, dll, linker, codeblocks

I am trying to use libcurl for a simple application using CodeBlocks IDE. In Codeblocks IDE, after clicking on Build Options ==> Linker Settings ==> Link Libraries ==> "Add" , the file browser only allows me to choose between *.a, *.so, *.lib, and *.dyl files. Why is it not allowing me to choose *.dll files? I downloaded the binary packages for Windows for libcurl and they all provide .dll files. This is what it looks like:

[image]

**====UPDATE====**

1. Hi I have now downloaded the following zip file for lib curl
   which includes CURL Source, DLL Files, and a .lib file. It can be
   found here: http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/curl-7.34.0-win64.zip

   However, I am still having issues being able to compile my source
   code.
2. Below is my source code:

## include

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

3. Below is a screen shot of my CodeBlocks IDE working directory:

[image]

4. Below are screen shots of my build options for Linker/Compiler, and Linker Libraries:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what is wrong with the setup. It is having trouble building. It is returning the following error messages:

[image]

Below is the latest Build Log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in libcurl_c (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Users\bbb\Desktop\libcurl_packages\confused_by_code\curl-7.34.0-win64\curl-7.34.0-win64\include  -c C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\workspace\libcurl_c\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\libcurl_c.exe obj\Debug\main.o    C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\libcurl_packages\confused_by_code\curl-7.34.0-win64\curl-7.34.0-win64\lib\libcurl.lib 
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:9: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:11: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:13: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:16: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:19: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
C:/Users/bbb/Desktop/workspace/libcurl_c/main.c:23: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
6 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A DLL (dynamic link library) is searched for and loaded by your program at runtime. To
make this happen automatically, you do not link the `.dll` itself (you can't). You link the matching *import library*, with extension `.lib`.

The import library for `libcurl.dll` is `libcurl.lib`. If you have downloaded and extracted `cURL`, say, into `C:\develop\curl-7.34.0-win32`, then you will find the import library at 
`C:\develop\curl-7.34.0-win32\lib\libcurl.lib`. You should add this file to the libraries
for your Code::Blocks project.

The project will then link (unless it has other problems), but in order for it to run successfully it will have to find `libcurl.dll` in one of the locations that are searched for DLLs at runtime. The simplest way to ensure this is to place a copy of `libcurl.dll` in the directory from which your program runs. Otherwise you can decide on a location for it by studying
[Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may have difficulty in finding the right binary package to download from
the plethora available [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). Some
of them are packages of the `cURL` commandline tools (which you don't want)
and some of them are packages of the development binaries (which you do want)
for various platforms. Visit http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/ and download
either `curl-7.34.0-win32.zip` or `curl-7.34.0-win64.zip`, depending on
whether you are targetting `win32` or `win64`. Extract the archive and
find the import library and DLL in the subdirectories `lib` and `dlls`,
respectively.

**Update for OP's further issues**

Your program is the supplied example `simple.c` with the addition of a C++ header, `<iostream>`.

- Delete your `libcurl` project and start again with a clean `C` project (not `C++`).
- Add only 1 source file to the C project, the example `simple.c` or a copy of it. Don't make it a `.cpp` file or otherwise change it. Don't add any other files to the project.
- In **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Link libraries** add the relative path to `libcurl.lib` as you did before.
- In **Build options** -> **Search Directories** -> **Compiler** (not **Linker**) add the relative path to the cURL `include` directory and nothing else (not the `include\curl` directory).
- Do not put anything in **Search directories** -> **Linker**.
- Build the project. It compiles and links for me.

**Update #2**

The problem now is that you are attempting to link the 64-bit `curl-7.34.0-win64\lib\libcurl.lib` with the 32-bit object code generated by your 32-bit toolchain, `mingw32`. You can't do that.

Replace your install of `curl-7.34.0-win64` with `curl-7.34.0-win32` from the same site. In your project, replace `your\path\to\curl-7.34.0-win64\lib\libcurl.lib` with `your\path\to\curl-7.34.0-win32\lib\libcurl.lib` and try again. The example will compile and link.

It will also run correctly, provided that it finds 32-bit `libcurl.dll` at runtime, and likewise the 32-bit DLLs that are dynamically loaded by `libcurl.dll` in turn. For the purpose of the example just copy all the DLLs from `your\path\to\curl-7.34.0-win32\dlls` into the same directory as the `.exe`. For regular development of `cURL` apps you would want the `cURL` libraries installed on the the system.

Since you chose to download 64-bit `cURL` in the first place, you may wish to build 64-bit
executables (although 32-bit executables will run on 64-bit hosts). You can't do that that
with your 32-bit toolchain, `mingw32`. You can install a 64-bit toolchain, e.g. [TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/?source=directory),
and configure it as an additional toolchain in C::B. Alternatively you could replace your
C::B installation with a C::B 13.12 one that has TDM-GCC pre-configured, from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/)

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your comment. I am quite new to using libraries in C++. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find any of these lib files. I downloaded several "packages" here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html . I downloaded win32_cygwin, win32_generic, win64_cygwin, win64_generic, win64_mingw64 and extracted all of them and in each of them, all I've seen are .exe files except for win64_mingw64 (which has libcurl.dll and libeay32.dll). However, in all of them, I have not seen a .lib file. Am I supposed to download the "Source Archive" from that page?

Comment: Hi Mike. I have updated my original post adding my source code, showing the codeblocks directory structure, and my build option linker/compiler settings. I am still having issues building the sample source code. Do you know what is wrong with the setup?

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your update. I dont know what is going on. I followed your instructions step by step. I created a brand new project with a clean C project. Then, I used the code from simple.c here: https://raw.github.com/bagder/curl/master/docs/examples/simple.c  Then, I went to build options=>linker settings=>link libraries and selected libcurl.lib . Then, I went to build options=>search directories=>compiler and added the relative path to include directory (not include\curl). I built the project and saw the same error message

Comment: did you try that with CodeBlocks IDE?

Comment: Yes of course built it with C::B. Rebuild your project from clean and post the build log from the **Build log** tab at the bottom of the IDE (not the **Build messages**)

Comment: Hi. I updated my original post and put the Build Log at the bottom of my post.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you Mike! Btw, I did not have to place the dll's anywhere. It seems to be able to do everything using just the include directory for "Compile" and the libcurl.lib for "Link Library"